# Why doesn't such a recursive Haskell function work?

Tags: haskell

Here is the codes:

```
rep' :: Int -> a -> [a]
rep' 0 x = []
rep' n x = x:rep'(n-1, x)
```

I tried to rewrite it like this:

```
rep' :: Int -> a -> [a]
rep' 0 x = []
rep' n x = x:(rep' n-1 x)
```

but it doesn't work either.

```
baby.hs:3:15-20: Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a0 -> [a0]’ …
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a (bound at /Users/hanfeisun/Workspace/haskell/baby.hs:3:8)
      rep' :: Int -> a -> [a]
        (bound at /Users/hanfeisun/Workspace/haskell/baby.hs:2:1)
    Probable cause: ‘rep'’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘rep' n’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(rep' n - 1 x)’
Compilation failed.
λ>
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Haskell functions are called `fun arg1 arg2 ...` not `fun(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Comment: @AJFarmar Both of those are perfectly legal depending on the type of `fun`. What matters is that you call the function with the same type as you defined it.

Comment: @sepp2k I realise that, but for the sake of learning Haskell, it's ideal to show beginners the curried method.

Comment: I am sure the type checker does have ideas about it!

Comment: When you include code which doesn't work, please include the actual problem as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell expresses its problems and expectations in the error messages, like this

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude|     let
Prelude|     {
Prelude|         rep' :: Int -> a -> [a];
Prelude|         rep' 0 x = [];
Prelude|         rep' n x = x:rep' (n-1, x);
Prelude|     }
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:73:22:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a0 -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of rep'
    Probable cause: rep' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `rep' (n - 1, x)'
    In the expression: x : rep' (n - 1, x)

<interactive>:73:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `(Int, a)'
    In the first argument of rep', namely `(n - 1, x)'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `rep' (n - 1, x)'
    In the expression: x : rep' (n - 1, x)
```

In the first section,

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a0 -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of rep'
    Probable cause: rep' is applied to too few arguments
```

says that, you have declared the return type of `rep'` as `[a]`, but it is returning `a0 -> [a0]`, which means it is returning a partially applied function. The possible problem is also given to you as a hint

```
    Probable cause: rep' is applied to too few arguments
```

so you might be passing fewer arguments to the function `rep'`. And in the next section, the line

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `(Int, a)'
```

says that it is expecting an `Int`, but it got `(Int, a)`. In Haskell, when you say `(n-1, x)`, it is treated as a tuple object, with two elements in it. So, you are actually invoking `rep'` with a single tuple object, not two parameters.

To actually invoke `rep'` with two parameters you can do like this

```
rep' n x = x:rep' (n-1) x
```

Now, you are calling `rep'` with two arguments, `(n-1)` and `x`.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude|     let
Prelude|     {
Prelude|         rep' :: Int -> a -> [a];
Prelude|         rep' 0 x = [];
Prelude|         rep' n x = x:rep' (n-1) x;
Prelude|     }
Prelude| :}
Prelude> rep' 5 100
[100,100,100,100,100]
```

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to `rep'` should be an `Int`, but when you call it as `rep' (n-1, x)` the first and only argument is a tuple.